# The basic jewish model for reward and punishment

Tags: reward-punishment

I'd like to understand what is known and not hidden by god in regards the accounting of mitzvas:

What happened after Yom Kipur - does god balance all my miztvas in comparison to sins I made in the previous year and then decide what will happen to me during this year? Are his options include:

- to reward me
- to make me suffer
- to kill me 
  as a result of my actions in the previous year?

Are the consequences of my actions from the previous year reset in the next Yom Kipur and not counted anymore or they are moved to another account that is taken into account again only when I eventually die in order to a assist god when he needs to decide if I go to heaven or to hell?

I'll appreciate the help to understand those basic accounting algorithm of Judaism that might increase my motivation to do mitzvas

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jack. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: The short answer is - we’re not entirely sure how G-d works. But there’s enough on the topic that I’ll try to compile an answer later.

Comment: There is a very interesting idea in *hasidut* that, even if you are forgiven fully on Yom Kippur, you still need to do *tshuva* again every year for the same sin because you are now a different person, on a higher level, and the *tshuva* from previous years was good for then, but not for the level you reached now. By doing *tshuva* every year, one erases those sins even for the level one has now reached